# Understanding types in the streaming libarary

Tags: haskell, streaming, monads

In regards to the [`streaming`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/streaming-0.2.1.0/docs/Streaming-Prelude.html) libarary What is `m` in `Stream (Of a) m r`? How could I figure this out from the documentation *(sorry, a noob here)*?

I'd like to understand what the type means so that I can work out my specific problem where I'm creating a stream of requests using servant, and while trying to consume it like this:

```
post :: Maybe Int -> ClientM [BlogPost]
post = ...

stream :: Stream (Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) ClientM ()
stream = S.map posts $ S.each $ [Just p | p <- [1..5]]

main = do
  let url = ...
  S.print $ S.map (\x -> runClientM x url) stream
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
• Couldn't match type ‘ClientM’ with ‘IO’
  Expected type: S.Stream (S.Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) IO ()
    Actual type: S.Stream (S.Of (ClientM [BlogPost])) ClientM ()
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If given in isolation, the `m` in `Stream (Of a) m r` could be any type.

When considering specific functions in the module, be aware of the type constraint. For example, the `yield` function has this type:

```
yield :: Monad m => a -> Stream (Of a) m ()
```

Here, `m` is constrained to be any type that's a `Monad` instance. This could be `IO`, `[]` (list), `Maybe`, `State`, `Reader`, etc.

Another function has this type:

```
stdinLn :: MonadIO m => Stream (Of String) m ()
```

Here, `m` is constrained to be any type that's a `MonadIO` instance. The `MonadIO` type class is a subclass of `Monad`, in the sense that for a type to be a `MonadIO`, it must already be a `Monad`.

AFAICT, `IO` is also a `MonadIO`, but e.g. `Maybe` isn't.

Thus, some of the functions in the module are more constrained than others. The `yield` function is less constrained than the `stdinLn` function. You can use `Maybe` as `m` with `yield`, but not with `stdinLn`.

Regarding your specific problem, there's not enough information in the OP for a repro, but it looks like `main` uses the `map` function from `Streaming.Prelude`:

```
map :: Monad m => (a -> b) -> Stream (Of a) m r -> Stream (Of b) m r
```

Here, `m` must be a `Monad` instance. In Haskell, the `main` function must have the type `IO ()`, so when using `do` notation, the `Monad` instance is inferred to be `IO`. The error message states that the compiler expects `m` to be `IO`.

Comment: Interesting note: by convention, a type variable named `m` almost always represents a monad (and `f` some other kind of functor).

Comment: A few other conventions: `f`,`g`,`h` for functions, `a`,`b`,`c` for type parameters, `s` for stream, end in `s` for lists/arrays/vectors, `v` for vector, suffix of `T` for transformer, prefix of `m` for `Maybe`, `e` for `Exception`, prefix of `e` for `Either`. Can you think of anymore?

Comment: @MCH The `m` prefix sometimes means `Monoid`, as in `mappend` and `mconcat`. Similarly (at least before *base-4.11.0.0*), the `s` prefix could also mean `Semigroup`, as in `sconcat` and `stimes`.